# First attempt at a python webscrape

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted an easy way to import a large database of crystallographic values into a program I'm working on. I installed Selenium and put together a simple script to scrape space groups and coordinates. There are a total of 230 space groups with a varying number of coordinates and possible translations to consider. [image: each group is displayed like this on a separate page]

Creating a dictionary to organize all space groups and letters seemed like the best way to go about it, and so this is what I came up with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import re, os

class SetOptions:
    def __init__(self, wyckoff, view, window):
        self.wyckoff=wyckoff
        self.driver_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
        # Driver options
        self.options=Options()
        self.options.headless = view
        self.options.add_argument(window)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options, executable_path=self.driver_path)
        # Strings found between the coordinate set on each page
        self.html_indices = ['Coordinates', 'specific']

    def scrape_positions(self, group, start, stop):
        space_groups = {}
        self.driver.get("https://www.cryst.ehu.es/cgi-bin/cryst/programs/nph-wp-list?gnum=%s" %(group))
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/input").click()
        raw_html=self.driver.page_source
         # Strip all html 
        stripped_html=re.sub('<[^>]+>', '', raw_html)
         # Split string data between identifier strings
        unsorted_pos = stripped_html.split(start)[1].split(stop)[0]
         # Parse translations, coordinates, letters, and multiplicities into line by line string
        sorted_pos = os.linesep.join([s for s in unsorted_pos.splitlines() if s])
         # Separate letter/multiplicity/symmetry strings from coordinate strings
        letters = re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', '', sorted_pos)
        regex = re.compile(".*?\((.*?)\)")
         # Check for the presence of translations and index that count
        centring_count = letters.split().count('+')
         # If present, parse translations separately as they will always occur before coordinates
        c_centring=[c for c in re.findall(regex, sorted_pos)[:centring_count][::-1]]
         # Once translations are removed from parenthetical strings only coordinate sets remain
        pos = [[pos] for pos in re.findall(regex, sorted_pos)[centring_count:][::-1]]
        # Join letter/multiplicity strings, discard sym strings
        letters=[s[:s.find(next(filter(str.isalpha, s)))+1]
        for s in letters.split() if s[0].isnumeric()][::-1]
        # if translations are present append the data to the end of letter/position lists
        if c_centring:
            base = centring_count
            letters.append('translation')
            pos.append(c_centring)
        else:
            base=1
        # Add each letter/multiplicity pair as keys with their corresponding coordinates
        for let in letters:
            index=[int(re.findall(r"\d+", let)[0])//base # add translations last 
            if letters.index(let) < len(letters)-1 else len(pos)][0]
            space_groups.update({let: pos[:index][::-1]})
            pos=pos[index:]

        return space_groups

    def update_groups(self, index_1, index_2):
        for i in range(index_1, index_2):
            self.wyckoff.update({i: self.scrape_positions(i, *self.html_indices)})
        # Print string data that is easily copied and pasted into a text editor
        return str(self.wyckoff).replace("['","[").replace("']","]")
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

wyckoff = {}
print(SetOptions(wyckoff, True, "--window-size=1920, 1200").update_groups(166,167))
```

Output:

```
> {166: {'3a': [[0,0,0]], '3b': [[0,0,1/2]], '6c': [[0,0,z], [0,0,-z]],
> '9d': [[1/2,0,1/2], [0,1/2,1/2], [1/2,1/2,1/2]], '9e':
> [[1/2,0,0], [0,1/2,0], [1/2,1/2,0]], '18f': [[x,0,0], [0,x,0],
> [-x,-x,0], [-x,0,0], [0,-x,0], [x,x,0]], '18g': [[x,0,1/2],
> [0,x,1/2], [-x,-x,1/2], [-x,0,1/2], [0,-x,1/2], [x,x,1/2]], '18h':
> [[x,-x,z],[x,2x,z], [-2x,-x,z], [-x,x,-z], [2x,x,-z], [-x,-2x,-z]],                   
> '36i':[[x,y,z], [-y,x-y,z], [-x+y,-x,z], [y,x,-z], [x-y,-y,-z],
> [-x,-x+y,-z], [-x,-y,-z], [y,-x+y,-z], [x-y,x,-z], [-y,-x,z],
> [-x+y,y,z], [x,x-y,z]], 'translation': [[1/3,2/3,2/3', '2/3,1/3,1/3',
> '0,0,0]]}}
```

Any feedback is welcome as I'm sure there are better approaches.